# collect and print multiple pages to single pdf file in linux

Tags: arch-linux, pdf

I have to print multiple documents from different applications (browsers, pdf readers etc) and print to a pdf file. What I want to do is collect the documents when i 'print' from these applications and be able to print those collected documents into a single PDF file. It would be even better if it allows some sort of editing or sorting of pages before i print to the PDF. Currently, I can print single files to pdfs using cups-pdf which shows up as a virtual pdf printer and then combine into one pdf file manually. It gets the job done but was wondering if there is an easy single step way.

Comment: Does [Gery's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19358402/4113344) on StackOverflow suit your needs?

Comment: @Nasha actually that is what I am doing currently. What I am looking for is easier solution which could act like a virtual printer which will just collect all the files i print from different applications into it and then i can print 1 pdf rght from the virtual printer. Or at least lets me append pages to the same pdf file every time i print to the same file.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be automated out-of-the-box. I'd say you need at least some scripting.

Comment: You can use iText library http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Boomaga](https://www.boomaga.org/) could meet your requirement, simply install it via `apt-get install -y boomaga`.

The program can also help you get your documents prepared a bit before printing. At this stage Boomaga makes it possible to:

- Paste several documents together.
- Print several pages on one sheet.
- 1, 2, 4, 8 pages per sheet
- Booklet. Folding the sheets in two, you’ll get a book.

Comment: This looks like a great solution. I needed to print 20 something pages, crashed on the first attempt but worked beautifully on the second :P

Answer (score 0):

[Shotwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotwell_(software)) is able to print multiple images on single page, combined with "print to file" does the trick.